# Kubernetes mariadb galera single node

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm, galera

I am trying to install galera mariadb on my cluster. I only have one node, but plan to scale in the future. It seems to install fine.

When deployed it says:

```
** Please be patient while the chart is being deployed **
Tip:
  Watch the deployment status using the command:
    kubectl get sts -w --namespace databases -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=galera
and then other things here
```

It tells me to check the status but the status is always:

```
galera-mariadb-galera   0/1     8m
```

**kubectl describe pod/galera-mariadb-galera-0     --namespace databases**

```
Name:           galera-mariadb-galera-0
Namespace:      databases
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=galera
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=mariadb-galera
                controller-revision-hash=galera-mariadb-galera-8d5cc8855
                helm.sh/chart=mariadb-galera-5.3.2
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=galera-mariadb-galera-0
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/galera-mariadb-galera
Containers:
  mariadb-galera:
    Image:       docker.io/bitnami/mariadb-galera:10.5.8-debian-10-r26
    Ports:       3306/TCP, 4567/TCP, 4568/TCP, 4444/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      bash
      -ec
      exec /opt/bitnami/scripts/mariadb-galera/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/mariadb-galera/run.sh
      
    Liveness:  exec [bash -ec exec mysqladmin status -u$MARIADB_ROOT_USER -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
] delay=120s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [bash -ec exec mysqladmin status -u$MARIADB_ROOT_USER -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
] delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MY_POD_NAME:                          galera-mariadb-galera-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:                        false
      MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_NAME:          galera
      MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_ADDRESS:       address-is-here-removed-unsure-if-private
      MARIADB_ROOT_USER:                    root
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD:                <set to the key 'mariadb-root-password' in secret 'galera-mariadb-galera'>  Optional: false
      MARIADB_USER:                         default-db-user
      MARIADB_PASSWORD:                     <set to the key 'mariadb-password' in secret 'galera-mariadb-galera'>  Optional: false
      MARIADB_DATABASE:                     default-db-name
      MARIADB_GALERA_MARIABACKUP_USER:      mariabackup
      MARIADB_GALERA_MARIABACKUP_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mariadb-galera-mariabackup-password' in secret 'galera-mariadb-galera'>  Optional: false
      MARIADB_ENABLE_LDAP:                  no
      MARIADB_ENABLE_TLS:                   no
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mariadb from data (rw)
      /opt/bitnami/mariadb/.bootstrap from previous-boot (rw)
      /opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf from mariadb-galera-config (rw,path="my.cnf")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-8qzpx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-galera-mariadb-galera-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  previous-boot:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  mariadb-galera-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      galera-mariadb-galera-configuration
    Optional:  false
  default-token-8qzpx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-8qzpx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age    From                Message
  ----     ------             ----   ----                -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   2m23s                      0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   2m23s                      0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  97s    cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added):
$:
```

I am unsure as to what might be causing the issue.

If I do:

```
kubectl logs pod/galera-mariadb-galera-0  --namespace databases
```

Nothing shows.

If I do:

```
 kubectl get pvc data-galera-mariadb-galera-0 --namespace databases


NAME                           STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
data-galera-mariadb-galera-0   Pending                                      do-block-storage   70m
```

**kubectl describe pvc data-galera-mariadb-galera-0 --namespace databases**

```
Name:          data-galera-mariadb-galera-0
Namespace:     databases
StorageClass:  do-block-storage
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app.kubernetes.io/instance=galera
               app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
               app.kubernetes.io/name=mariadb-galera
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    galera-mariadb-galera-0
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                   From                                                                                           Message
  ----     ------                ----                  ----                                                                                           -------
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  3m59s (x26 over 10m)  persistentvolume-controller                                                                    waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "dobs.csi.digitalocean.com" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal   Provisioning          85s (x10 over 10m)    dobs.csi.digitalocean.com_master-cluster-id-here  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "databases/data-galera-mariadb-galera-0"
  Warning  ProvisioningFail
```

The issue above was I had too many existing storages open. I now deleted them and have redeployed.

Comment: Please add the output of  ```kubectl get pvc data-galera-mariadb-galera-0``` to your question

Comment: Thanks I have added the output to the bottom of the question

Comment: PVC is in `pending` state and till the time it gets into `Bound` state POD will not get to `running` state. Please add ``` kubectl describe pvc data-galera-mariadb-galera-0 ``` also to your question

Comment: I added to the bottom, thanks

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working now, issue was existing volumes. You can create answer now for me to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pod is in "Pending" state due to the fact that the PVC "data-galera-mariadb-galera-0" is in unbound state.Once the PVC comes to Bound state then the POD will come to running state.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as `Community Wiki` to expand comment and above answer.

Generally `MariaDB` cannot be deployed as this setup require `PersistentVolume` which should be created using [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) as OP is using cloud environment - [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/). As `PersistentVolume` was not created it couldn't bound with `PersistentVolumeClaim`, thus `pod` stuck in `Pedning` state.

As OP stated in the bottom of the question:

> The issue above was I had too many existing storages open. I now deleted them and have redeployed.

Kubernetes is not able to create it due to `DigitalOcean` [Limits](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/volumes/#limits). OP stated that is using one node and already had 10 storages.

> - Unverified users can have up to **10 volumes per region** and up to a total of 500 GB of disk space per region.
> - By default, users can create up to 100 volumes and up to a total of 16 TiB of disk space per region. You can contact our support team to request an increase. **You can attach a maximum of 7 volumes to any one node or Droplet, and this limit cannot be changed.**